# Passing JVM option to forked test in SBT

Tags: sbt

I am trying to use a JVM option in a forked test, which has been set externally to SBT prior to its launch. I'm also setting additional JVM options like so:

```
javaOptions in ThisBuild ++= List("-Xmx3072m")
```

to my understanding, based on [the SBT documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.3/docs/Detailed-Topics/Forking.html) the JVM options provided to the SBT process should be available to the forked process:

> By default, a forked process uses the same Java and Scala versions being used for the build and the working directory and JVM options of the current process.

However, I can't seem to retrieve those "external" JVM options in the forked tests, i.e. `System.getProperty("foo")` will always return null. Given that I am trying to pass along a password, I can't set it directly in the build file. My questions therefore are:

- is there an SBT task / key to access the JVM options passed to the JVM in which SBT is running? That way I would attempt to add the key to the `javaOptions`
- is there any other means by which to pass external Java Options to a forked test?

Comment: For the Internet passerby, there is an example of how to pass options to forked JVMs [here on the sbt issue tracker](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1032#issuecomment-30108848).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may control your options with `testGrouping`. Below copy'n'paste from one of my projects. It properly handles hierarchical projects and root project without tests too. Options are merged from `javaOptions in run` and `test.options` file. This allow modify arguments without project reloading. That project has load time more then minute. So I use `test.options` to fast switch between production and debug mode with `-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_`...

```
testGrouping in Test <<= (definedTests in Test, javaOptions in run, baseDirectory in LocalRootProject) map { (tests, javaOptions, baseDirectory) ⇒
  if (tests.nonEmpty) {
    val testOptionsFile = baseDirectory / "test.options"
    val externalOptions = if (testOptionsFile.exists()) {
      val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile(testOptionsFile)
      val options = source.getLines().toIndexedSeq
      source.close()
      options
    } else Nil
    tests map { test ⇒
      new Tests.Group(
        name = test.name,
        tests = Seq(test),
        //          runPolicy = Tests.InProcess)
        runPolicy = Tests.SubProcess(javaOptions = javaOptions ++ externalOptions))
    }
  } else {
    Seq(new Tests.Group(
      name = "Empty",
      tests = Seq(),
      runPolicy = Tests.InProcess))
  }
},
```

Comment: Thankyou. I've been trying to split my Play app into sub-modules and been having a nightmare with forking not taking my settings across.